# BUSCAR una persona en la base de datospor su ID en Visual Basic

Tags: base-de-datos, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ms-access

He intentado de todo y me sigue saliendo error. Porfavor ayudenme. Debo presentar este trabajo mañana!El error es la parte de asignar el adaptador OleDBDataAdapter y el Fill. "**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'"

```
    conectar()
    Dim buscar As String = "Select * FROM datos WHERE id=@id"
    Dim CNN As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(buscar, CNN)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", CInt(TextBox1.Text))
    Dim adpata As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim tabla As New DataTable
    adpata.Fill(tabla)
    Try
        If tabla.rows.count > 0 Then
            Dim row As DataRow = tabla.Rows(0)
            TextBox1.Text = (CStr(row.Item("id")))
            TextBox2.Text = (CStr(row.Item("nombre")))
            TextBox3.Text = (CStr(row.Item("apellido")))
        Else
        MsgBox("No se encontro la persona ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "advertencia")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
               cnn.Close()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Veo que tenes dos preguntas similares, ahora te pongo una respuesta en cada una, pero el error es muy similar y es de concepto.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, creaste una conexión, pero nunca le dijiste cuales eran los parametros de la misma. O sea, tu conexion no sabe a donde conectarse.

Lo que te falta es justamente agregarle eso:

```
Dim CNN As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("parametros de conexion")
```